# NDSolve numerical problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to solve a couple of differential equations given by:

$$F(H(t))=R(\phi(t))$$

$$\phi(t)''+H(t) \phi'(t)+ m \,\phi(t)=0$$

where $m=1$ and $F$ and $R$ are just particular functions.

[image]

In the image you can see the initial conditions. The red curve is $F(u(t))$ and the black horizontal line shows the initial conditions / set up i.e. $R(\phi(0))$ when integration begins.

The point is that if I change smoothly the values which characterizes the curve i.e. I change the $\phi(0)$ value shifting the black line up or down; then, `NDSolve` changes the initial condition arbitrarily with the next output:

***`NDSolve` has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the 
differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from 
those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial 
conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is 
recommended***

I know that's an `NDSolve` problem because unless I choose a value where the black line is bigger than the value of the red line, the solutions should exist so I don't really know why Mathematica produces this.

The code is the following:

```
V[x_, m_] := 1 / 2 m^2 x^2;

m = 1;
ϕtilde = 1;
μ = 72;
β = 172;
σ = 22;
nEND = {};
solutions =
    NDSolve[{
      Evaluate[
        3 (((1 + E^(μ^2 / (2 σ^2) - (-μ + ℋ[n]^2)^2 / (2 σ^2))) (1 + Tanh[β ℋ[n]^2]) ℋ[n]^2) / (2 (1 + ((μ + 2 β σ^2) ℋ[n]^2) / (2 σ^2)))) ==
            1 / 2 ψ[n]^2 + V[Φ[n], m]
      ],
      Evaluate[ℋ[n] ψ'[n] + 3 ℋ[n] ψ[n] + Derivative[1, 0][V][Φ[n], m] == 0],
      Evaluate[ψ[n] == ℋ[n] Φ'[n]], Φ'[0] == 0, ψ[0] == 0, Φ[0] == ϕtilde,
      WhenEvent[Im[ℋ[n]] != 0, "StopIntegration"],
      WhenEvent[Φ[n] < 0, nEND = Append[nEND, n]; "StopIntegration"]},
      {ℋ, Φ, ψ}, {n, 0, 10^12}]
```

When I change slightly some of the initial numbers which only means to uplift or downlift the black line over the curve so solution should exist with the particular initial condition fixed, mathematica changes arbitrarly the initial condition or it doesn't perform the integration directly when I already know that the solution should exist. 
P.S: Sorry about greek letters, I don't know how to put it here...

---

v2 Additional info / answers: 
firstly thanks to all of you.

1) My Mathematica version is 11.3.0.0

2) The psi variable is defined by:

psi[n] ==H[n] phi'[n]

It's just the derivative of phi multiplied by H(n) but in the picture psi=0, because at initial "time" n=0, psi(n)=0.

3) Thanks for the greek letters correction!

4) I don't really get it last comment about AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal, what do you mean? I can try with that precision and it works the code but the problem remains equally. thanks everyone

Comment: We can't tell you nothing without looking your code.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry. I thought the code was there. And I also don't know how to put greek letters here, it's my first post, sorry.

Comment: Your code sample produces a result without warning in _v9.0.1_ and _v12.1_. Which version are you in?

Comment: There are phi and psi in the algebraic differential system in your Mathematica code, but not in the picture. There is only phi. Please provide psi.

Comment: The easiest way to get Greek letters correct it to use [this add-on to the editor](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor)

Comment: Mathematica NDSolve is made for several purposes or optimized. One is be quiet. So for a tough NDSolve run at WorkingPrecision and InterpolationOrder -> \[Infinity]. If you allow for , AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4 this is not so good.  You will see Your work around is not a good as NDSolve shows up without.